# Google Data Studio - Advanced Filter "Which other brands do customers of a spefic brand buy"

Tags: dashboard, looker-studio

My datasets contains the following columns:
- person_ID
- brand
- purchase_date

Now I'd like to use Google Data Studio to create a Dashboard which shows what other brands are purchased by persons who also bought brand X.

```
with identification as

(
select person_ID
where brand = 'X'
from dataset
)

select count(distinct(data.person_ID)), data.brand
from dataset data
    inner join identification ident on data.person_id = ident.person_id
```

Using Google Data Studio to transform the SQL-code (shown above) in an interactive dashboard solution.

"what other brands are purchased by persons who also bought brand X"

Comment: Hi superdell. I'm unsure what the issue you are actually having is?

Comment: Lets say 100 persons purchased brand X - now I'd like to use Google Data Studio to figure out which other brands those 100 persons have purchased aswell.
I can easily solve this issue using SQL but i have no idea how to use Google Data Studio as a dashboard solution.

Answer (score 1):

So first you need to get your data into the format you want to present it in. The following SQL should provide data which has every combination of product bought by a customer for example.

```
SELECT data1.brand brand_purchased, data2.brand other_brands_purchased, 
count(distinct(data.person_ID)) uniqueCustomers
FROM dataset data1
INNER JOIN dataset data2 on data1.person_id = data2.person_id 
AND data1.brand <> data2.brand
```

Once you've got the data in a format you need, you'd link that via a connector to data studio.

You can then choose the presentation style you wish to show back to the customer (bar chart, table, etc) and add a filter which has the "brand_purchased" dimension to filter your data by.

It's hard to tell you exactly what to do as there are so many viable solutions depending on how you store your data and how you want to visualise it.

Data Studio's strength is in visualising the data especially to those who aren't data savvy. If you're strong in SQL however, you may find it easier to get to the answers you need through SQL.